# UIScrollView with a UITableView mechanism

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad

I am looking for a third party library that would allow me to use a UIScrollView with a UITableView mechanism, so it will have something like viewForRowAtIndexPath, numberOfRowsAtIndexPath.. reusing views. I know a UITableView is a subclass of UIScrollView, but I want to do more customization that will be kind of hard when using UITableView.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve that can't be done with a UITableView?

Answer (score 0):

Since `UITableViewCell` is a subclass of `UIView`, you could use a custom `UITableViewCell`, adding your view as the `UITableViewCell`'s subview.  I am assuming that all your views are of the same size.  (In the table view controller's init method, remember to set self.tableView.rowHeight to a value that will accommodate the heights of your views.)

See the **Customizing Cells** section of **Apple's Table View Programming Guide for iOS** for more info.